# How do I stop GameObjects from respawning at every frame?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I've come across this little issue which I can't seem to fully understand how to solve, I've tried changing my codes countless times but I haven't gotten anywhere :(

I am creating game objects programmatically which works fine, but the issue is that the game creates the objects once per frame (not exactly what I want)! So I've put in a time delay of 10 seconds but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
public Vector3 spawnLocation;
public GameObject myCube;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    if (myCube.renderer.enabled == false) {
        Debug.Log("myCube not rendered");
        myCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    }
    if (myCube == null) {
        Debug.Log("myCube not set");
        myCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    StartCoroutine(Delay());
    Destroy(myCube, 5);
    CreateCube();
}

void CreateCube() {

    spawnLocation = new Vector3(24, 17, -28);
    StartCoroutine(Delay());
    Instantiate(myCube, spawnLocation, Quaternion.identity);
}

IEnumerator Delay(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
}
```

The objects appear endlessly at every frame -_-

Could anyone please help point me in the right direction where am going off.
And is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You're calling `CreateCube()` every time the game loops. Stick it in `Start()`.

Comment: @David I tried that, but if I place `CreateCube()` in `Start()` it only creates the gameobject once! I want to create `myCube` endlessly but with a time interval.

Comment: // Update() is called every frame. If you're new, avoid using it until you learn how to implement an event pattern or you'll run into nightmares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've put in a time delay of 10 seconds but it doesn't seem to work
>   properly.

Delay works but you are still Instantiating the cubes inside Update.
If you want to instantiate a Cube every 10 seconds you cand do the following:

```
IEnumerator DelayCreateCube(float delay){

    while(true)
    {
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
      Instantiate(myCube, spawnLocation, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}

public void Start()
{
  StartCoroutine(DelayCreateCube());
}
```

Coroutines are executed by the engine at every frame (well, it depends on the coroutine) generally (at least in your case) immediately after all the `Update` methods of all `GameObjects` have been called.

When you use `StartCoroutine`, it simply schedules the coroutine to be executed later, so it doesn't block the execution of `Update` method:

```
StartCoroutine(Delay());
Destroy(myCube, 5);
CreateCube();
```

in the code above `Delay` will be executed only after Update method has returned, so you were not actually delaying the execution of `Destroy` and `CreateCube` methods.

For a more detailed description of coroutines, have a look at this [article](http://unitygems.com/coroutines/).

---

EDIT

Just an additional consideration. I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but it seems that you want to create and destroy a primitive at always the same location. If you haven't a good reason to do that, you can simply `enable/disable` the object instead of creating a new one and destroy it again (for performances).

Comment: Did you mean to call the `DelayCreateCube(delay)` in `Start()`?

Comment: @Kap: yes my fault :). I fixed it.

Comment: I'm trying to create a primitive then destroy it after a few seconds and repeat the same actions. After a certain amount of time, I want to be able to create 2 or more primitives at the same time with a 3-5 seconds interval.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the `myCube` gameObject now appear after a specified delay of my choice. However, it doesn't appear in the same location...I've tried tweaking the `SpawnLocation()` but i'm still having the same problem. Is there something I'm missing or have extra lines of code(s) causing this issue? :(

Answer (score 1):

Obviously other people have pointed out the fact that you are creating a cube every time Update() is called, which is once every game loop. Assuming you only want to create objects at an even interval of time, e.g. once every X seconds, you should consider using either a Coroutine or an InvokeRepeating. Coroutine solution has already been addressed, [InvokeRepeating](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) is given below:

```
void Start()
{
  InvokeRepeating("CreateCube", 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void CreateCube()
{
    // create your cube here
}
```

Comment: +1: good to know, I didn't know that. Probably using a coroutine already implemented in the engine is even more faster than writing your own code. thanks